# Kerr geodesics differential equations in equatorial plane

Tags: general-relativity, black-holes, simulations, kerr-metric

With friend, we are writing an interactive educational simulation of particle falling into a black hole.

Currently we use [Schwarzschild geodesics](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Schwarzschild_geodesics#Geodesic_equation). However, we want to generalize it to the case of [rotating](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Kerr_metric) (and perhaps [rotating and charged](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Kerr%E2%80%93Newman_metric)) black hole. We are mostly interested in the equatorial plane, as then we can plot it on a 2D tablet.

So, **what are the differential equations for a particle (with given initial position and velocity) falling in the Kerr (or Kerr-Newman) metrics in the equatorial plane?**

I'm interested in an explicit form (**plug & play** - should work after insertion of the black hole parameters (i.e. $M, L, Q$) and the initial contitions (i.e. $\vec{x}, \vec{v}, q$); $Q$ and $q$ are optional, as Kerr metrics is nice by itself).

Side notes:

Yes, I know the general procedure. Just I'm short of time (so now I'm even no longer coding it). So I may self-answer, but rather later than sooner.

It's almost in [Chapter 20 of something: Geodesic motion in Kerr spacetime](http://www.roma1.infn.it/teongrav/VALERIA/TEACHING/ONDE_GRAV_STELLE_BUCHINERI/AA2010_2011/LEZIONI_MIE_BH/kerrgeod.pdf) (i.e. (20.25) and (20.31) for the equations of motion; (20.18) and  (20.19) for energy and angular momentum). However, some parameters are not introduced (perhaps there are in the previous chapters...).

Comment: I don't have the book handy at the moment, but you should (at least, that's where I would) check Chapter 4 of B. O'Neill's _The Geometry of Kerr Black Holes_

Answer (score 5, accepted):

I'll follow *Gravitation* by Misner, Thorne, and Wheeler (hereafter MTW), which is the standard <strike>reference textbook</strike> encyclopedic tome for the field despite its age.

Let $\lambda$ parametrize the path such that the derivative with respect to it gives the 4-momentum. Using Boyer-Lindquist coordinates, MTW Box 33.5 gives
$$ \left(\frac{\mathrm{d}r}{\mathrm{d}\lambda}\right)^2 = \frac{1}{r^4} \left(\alpha E^2 - 2\beta E + \gamma_0\right), $$
where
$$ E = \frac{1}{\alpha} \left(\beta + \sqrt{\beta^2 - \alpha\gamma_0 + \alpha r^4(p^r)^2}\right) $$
is a constant of the motion (energy at infinity) and we have
$$ \alpha = \left(r^2 + a^2\right)^2 - \Delta a^2 \\
\beta = \left(L_z a + qQr\right) \left(r^2 + a^2\right) - L_z a\Delta \\
\gamma_0 = \left(L_z a + qQr\right)^2 - \Delta L_z^2 - m^2r^2\Delta \\
\Delta = r^2 - 2Mr + a^2 + Q^2.
$$
Here $m$ is the test particle's rest mass and $L_z$ is its (conserved) angular momentum at infinity. $a = L/M$ is the black holes's angular momentum per unit mass. ($L$ not related to $L_z$ - sorry about that.)

For the azimuthal motion, I turn to MTW Eq. 33.32c, which states (after setting $\theta = \pi/2$)
$$ \frac{\mathrm{d}\phi}{\mathrm{d}\lambda} = -\frac{1}{r^2} \left(\frac{aP}{\Delta} - aE + L_z\right). $$
Here we define
$$ P = E \left(r^2 + a^2\right) - L_z a - qQr. $$

The final step is finding the relation between time $t$ (of the Boyer-Lindquist variety, which means it's not crazy) and $\lambda$. MTW Eq. 33.32d tells us (again after setting $\theta = \pi/2$)
$$ \frac{\mathrm{d}t}{\mathrm{d}\lambda} = \frac{1}{r^2} \left(\frac{P}{\Delta} \left(r^2 + a^2\right) - a^2E + aL_z\right). $$

Hope this helps. I remember coding something similar (alright, plugging the ODEs into Mathematica) once upon a time. It seemed to work reasonably well without needing any fancy numerical techniques to ensure stability... at least for a few orbits, after which I couldn't tell what it was supposed to be doing.

Comment: If anyone reading this wants a character-building experience, I recommend Exercise 33.7 of MTW, which derives these equations in all their gory detail. I should mention though: I'm reasonably sure there's a sign error or two buried in some of the intermediate equations given in the exercise - don't loose as much sleep as I did when you come across it.

Comment: Thanks! However, what does "MTW" stand for? (A book I guess.)

Comment: Yes, Misner, Thorne and Wheeler. text book "Gravitation"

Comment: @Jim Thanks. Edited. I sometimes forget the book has a title other than those initials.

Comment: @PiotrMigdal: I would also advise reading a bit about the behavior of the Kerr orbits--in particular, the co-rotating orbits and the anti-co-rotating orbits will behave differently and have different points of instability.  This should be a decent check on your code.